# XSLT for-each loop transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I've just been given a task to transform some data but unfortunately I've not touched XSLT before and so I rather new to the concepts. I've been able to transform static content but the files I've been asked contain table like structures with varying number of rows and columns.

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is the same thing but translated to HTML.

Here's a sample of pseudo XML that I need to translate.

```
<document>
<item> 
    <richtext>
    <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
        <mytable>
            <myrow>
            <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
            <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
                <mycol colspan="2" >Data 1 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 2 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 3 </mycol>
            </myrow>
        </mytable>
        <mytable>
            <myrow>
                <mycol colspan="2" >Data 1 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 2 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 3 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 4 </mycol>
            </myrow>
        </mytable>
</item>
<item> 
    <richtext>
    <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
        <mytable>
            <myrow>
            <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
            <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
                <mycol colspan="2" >Data 1 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <rubbishToIgnore> Don't include this </rubbishToIgnore>
                <mycol>Data 2 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 3 </mycol>
            </myrow>
        </mytable>
        <mytable>
            <myrow>
                <mycol colspan="2" >Data 1 </mycol>
            </myrow>
            <myrow>
                <mycol>Data 2 </mycol>
            </myrow>
        </mytable>
</item>
```

I'm just looking for some pointers/assistance to the correct way to loop through the XML using XSLT and create a simple HTML table.

This is the XSLT pseudo-code I was thinking of.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document/item>
<xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext>
<xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext/mytable">
    <table border = "1">
        <xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext/myrow">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext/mycol">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="document/item/richtext/mycol"/>
                    <td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            <tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In the meantime I'll try and figure this out myself by going through the W3schools tutorials.

Thanks guys/girls! :)

Comment: Deeply nested xsl:for-each instructions is usually the wrong approach. Break it up into template rules that match different elements in the input; when processing one element, use xsl:apply-templates to invoke the appropriate processing on its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your nested `xsl:for-each` statements. The second one isn't going to select anything...

```
<xsl:for-each select="document/item">
  <xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext">
```

This is because the first `xsl:for-each` selects an `item` element, and so your nested `xsl:for-each` statement will be relative to that `item` element. In other words it is looking for a child element called `document` which is obviously not there.

In fact, you don't need these first two statements at all. You can just use the third one to get the elements directly.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext/mytable">
```

The same issue with selecting child nodes applies to the rest of your `xsl:for-each` statements too. So, for example, to select rows you would do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="myrow">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="document/item/richtext/mytable">
    <table border = "1">
      <xsl:for-each select="myrow">
        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="mycol">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However, if you intend to do more XSLT, you might want to consider using an approach that uses templates. Not that there is any issue with for-each statements, but in this case it would help reduce nesting, and the size of the code blocks.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document/item/richtext/mytable" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mytable">
  <table border = "1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="myrow" />
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myrow">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mycol" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mycol">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And if you want to include the `colspan` attribute, change the "mycol" matching template to this...

```
<xsl:template match="mycol">
  <td>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@colspan" />
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your help and clear explanation, that's really helped a lot and is working for me!